# Going back to first ViewController from second ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm building an app that currently has 3 ViewControllers. One of them is used after a successful login so is not relevant in this question.

I'm using a mixture of Storyboards and building things programmatically when I find Storyboards do not give me the fine control that I need.

The first ViewController is built in my 'MainStoryboard'. It has a login form and an info button at the bottom. I link it up the my AppDelegate by doing the following inside **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Because I wanted to force rendering of a UIWebView (another story) I create the second view programmatically. I do the following inside **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
[infoViewController view];
```

Inside both of my ViewControllers I setup a link to appDelegate as below:

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

I have an info button in my first ViewController that takes you to the infoViewController. It calls the following code when tapped:

```
appDelegate.infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.infoViewController animated:YES];
```

The above works just fine for me, flips over the screen and shows the InfoViewController.

On my InfoViewController I have a button that should take you back to the login page, I have tried all sorts to get this to work but it just crashes my app. Nothing seems to work. I have tried the following:

```
appDelegate.viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.viewController animated:YES];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:appDelegate.viewController animated:YES];
```

I suspect the last 3 might be more to do with when you have a navigation view controller and you want to go back to the root? I'm not sure, but either way it does not work. I had this working using storyboards previously so I'm sure it ought to be easy! As mentioned I switched to making the infoViewController programmatically so that I could force the UIWebView to render before the view appeared.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I think the dismissModalViewController answers below are right.  On a side note, what are you accomplishing with [infoViewController view]; ??  Also, you can setup that controller's transition style when you create it.

Comment: Hi, I will try the suggestions below a bit later (end of my lunch break and back to my PHP/JS day job). [infoViewController view] literally just shows a UIWebView that contains some info about the App. I suspect that maybe you'd think I ought to just show this info in another view in the first ViewController? I've only really been doing ObjC/iOS for 3-4 weeks so it's likely I'm not entirely following best practices.

Comment: Gotcha, but view is just a property of ViewController.  It's the view that is managed by the view controller... not a verb, but a noun.  I think it's nil at the point you're asking for it.  (It can cause a state change the first time the view controller has been loaded from a nib, which is to do the first, lazy load of the view, but you usually don't need to worry about that.  The presentation just works).  Try commenting that line, and see if it doesn't behave identically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do with:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use this.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a main controller for switching between your other view controllers. Change the view of your root controller to one of your other view controllers (apply animations as usual if needed). Hold a pointer to your root controller in your other view controllers and call `self.rootController.view = <desired_controller_instance>.view`

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you're presenting your InfoViewController is wrong. Do it the following way:

In your ViewController, create an action for the info button.:

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
   InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
   infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
   [self presentModalViewController:infoViewController animated:YES];
}
```

And in your InfoViewController, in the action of your button that should take you back write this:

```
- (void)takeBackToViewController
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Also in presented controller you can use this

```
if(self.parentViewController)
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
else
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To dissmiss current controller.