# How to use custom back button to return to main view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to programmatically get my custom back button to return to the main view controller (ie. from 'view controller for Home1' to the 'main view controller') - check link
http://postimg.org/image/cnoq0hsct/

Comment: ok, what is the issue ?

Comment: Well i'm new to ios app dev and it's my first time working with custom buttons so i'm not sure about the code.

Comment: you need to write an IBAction and connect that to button or simply you can add a segue using storyboard

Comment: possible duplicate of [Going back to first ViewController from second ViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721771/going-back-to-first-viewcontroller-from-second-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect an IBAction and use this code:

```
- (IBAction)yourAction:(id)sender
{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you perform a segue programmatically

```
  - (IBAction)BackButton:(id)sender {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueFromHomeToMain" sender:self];
    }
```

if you wanna pass data to main you can use the `prepareForSegue` method

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueFromHomeToMain"])

     }
```